# Is linear prefix average method better than quadratic prefix average method?

Tags: java, array-algorithms

I've created a method (based on pseudocode I found online) to compute prefix averages for an array but I'm not sure I've satisfied the requirement.

**The requirement is:**

> Given an array a[1…n] of n numbers, compute another array b[1…n] also
>   of length n such that b[i] is the average of a[0]…a[i], for 0 <= i <=
>   n.

I looked around and found pseudocode for linear and quadratic versions of prefix average methods, and created my own implementation of each.

**Here is the linear version:**

```
public static double[] prefixAverages1 (double[] n) {
        double b[] = new double[n.length]; 
        double s = 0;    
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            s += n[i]; 
            b[i] = s/(i+1);
        }
        return b; 
}
```

**Here is the quadratic version:**

```
public static double[] prefixAverages2 (double[] n) {
        double b[] = new double[n.length];  
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            double t = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                t += n[j];
            }
            b[i] = t/(i+1);
        }
        return b;
}
```

**My Question:**

Do both of these functions satisfy the requirement and if so, which one is better?

Comment: It looks like both methods satisfy the requirement. A linear running time is faster than a quadratic, so the first one is best (from a running time perspective).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for us to review or test code.

Answer (score 1):

Linear is better as it takes less execution time -O(n)
While Quadratic will take more time- O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think both functions satisfy the requirement. I can't see any reason you should choose the quadratic solution over the linear one in this problem.